# Trying to print a char stored in a 2 dimension array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Sample code :

```
char map [20][20];
map [0] [0]=1;
printf ("%s\n", map[0][0]);
```

At the compiling process, I get this warning:

`warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’`

Although if I write `printf ("%s\n", &map[0][0]);` it somehow works properly.

Why is this?

Edit:

Sorry my bad Jeff. If i try this

```
map [0][0]='X';
printf ("%s\n", map[0][0]);
```

I still get the same warning.

Comment: it would be helpful if you tag your question with the language you are using.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to print? Both of your format strings suggest you're trying to print a *string*, yet your question and variadic parameter being pushed into the `printf()` call suggest you're trying to print a *single-character*. So which is it you want? A string (i.e. map[0]) or a single char (i.e. map[0][0]) ?

Answer (score 1):

In the code you posted you are attempting to format a string `%s` as a result the printf method expects a char* to be passed. if you pass it an int or a single char it will issue a warning as it does.

to print a single char as per your example you would need:

```
printf("%c\n", map[0][0]);
```

The reason it works when you pass in the `&map[0][0]` is because you are now passing in a pointer to a character ( `char*` ) which is the same as passing it an array of characters.

See the [printf reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Answer (score 0):

With char itself being a numerical value, an 8-bit integer, such code gets you that warning. As for your second issue, taking the address of map[0][0] using the "address of" operator gets you a pointer to the first element of map[0], or the value 1 in this case, and printf takes a pointer to an array of char.
consider this:

```
char map [20];
map [0]=1;
printf ("%s\n", map); //or printf ("%s\n", &map[0])
```

both point to the first element, effectively printing until null, '\0' is reached in the array.

EDIT: Regarding your edit, you are still accessing the first element, which is of type char, numerical in nature. The 'X' gets you the numerical equivalent of that character.

Answer (score 0):

it works because you sent the address of the first element (char *) type.. the parameter gets DECAYED inside the printf function which wants a char pointer pointing to a character array in your case